# Is there anything I can do to help for the party?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this question grammatical?

"Is there anything I can do to help for the party?"

I saw it on an English class whiteboard.

I think it's supposed to be "with" instead of "for".

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite grammatical English, but is quite typical of informal speech. Compare a few closely related constructions:

Is there anything I can do, to help prepare for the party? (Grammatically correct; sounds slightly formal and old-fashioned.)

Is there anything I can do for you, to help with the party? (Grammatically correct; quite natural speech.)

Is there anything I can do toward the party? (Quite natural; implies something like "toward making arrangements for the party". Here of course, "toward" implies action toward some objective, rather than actual motion.)

The sentence you quote also has some implied words.

These work well if the party in question is a birthday party or other similar gathering. If the object is a political party, the construction should be different:

Is there anything I can do to help the party? (Grammatically correct; quite natural speech.)